# Everytime I try to add a device (Alcatel) to google account or says login to original owners account

Tags: factory-reset, google-account

Everytime I try to link my alcatel one touch to my google account or says login with original owners account. Ive reset this phone a hundred times and it says the same thing even though there is no account linked. What the hell do I do??

Comment: You bought this device new from your servicer? Not second-hand? You're sure there is no previous owner?

Answer (score 1):

See:
http://www.kriztekblog.com/2017/06/bypass-frp-alcatel-android-devices.html

I unlocked my Alcatel Pixi Pulsar a460g with an altered version of method 4:

- Hold power and up volume buttons to hard reset, let go of power button and keep holding up volume.
- Select "clear cache"
- Select wipe device"
- Select reboot
- Start android
- When asked to pick network, select Adavnced.
- Select Settings
- Select Backup and reset
- Choose Erase
- Agree all Protection will not work.
- Click "Erase Everything"

Answer (score 0):

This is because the previous owner have put their account, putting yours won"t work simply because the phone is linked to that account.

Now you need that account to be able to use the phone. Or, you can try hundred of tutorials on how to bypass a factory reset protection (FRP an equivalent to iCloud lock mechanism) on android.